# Single post not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site was not showing blog posts content and not the single post content, so I have created a blog template and used a post grid plugin shortcode. So now the blog is showing fine, but when I click on "Read more" it directs to single post, which shows empty page, I have disabled and enabled plugins and checked my htaccess file also. Thank you.

```html
<?php 
/*
* Template Name: Blog Post
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>
  <?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>
 </title>
 <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <?php wp_head();?>
</head>


 <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode("[post_grid id='605']"); ?>




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Is it really empty? Did you `View Source` in your browser? Is it a completely white page? Either way, turn on error reporting.  In your wp-config.php file, set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`.  That should cause it to show the error(s) that are causing the issue.

Comment: where is your single file code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `<body>` tag and also may be missing the WordPress loop in between the `<body>...</body>` tags.

Try this:

```
<body>
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
</body>
```

Additionally the `<?php get_header(); ?>` already contains the HTML `<head></head>` and all the links and meta within, so you are essentially duplicating/overwriting it.

Try doing this:

```
<?php 
/*
* Template Name: Blog Post
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
</body>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Do also make sure that your `header.php` file doesn't actually contain the opening `<body>` tag out of the box though (`footer.php` should contain the closing tag), as this will determine whether you need the `<body></body>` tags in my code above.